# Mapbox - Navigating a custom route (turn-by-turn)

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've been exploring the Mapbox Map SDK and the Navigation SDK and have hit a brick wall so any help would be appreciated.

I have a few routes defined in GeoJSON. Is it possible to feed this custom route in GeoJSON into the Navigation SDK and get turn-by-turn directions?

Perhaps with the help of this plugin:

https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/plugins/overview/geojson/#using-the-geojson-plugin

I realise there also is a Map Matching API:

[image: Map Matching Android Service]

https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-matching/

Which seem like a perfect way to snap all the geocoordinates to the road so that there is no bleed.

Now the undocumented part or the part that I am having trouble with is with a route properly defined in GeoJSON, can Mapbox provide turn-by-turn navigation directions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi Francis, have you already found a correct solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Navigation SDK will take in any DirectionsRoute and try navigating along it, that is if all the necessary information is found in the object. For your case, you might want to try as you mentioned, Map Matching beforehand and using the [MapMatchingMatching](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/libjava-services/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/api/mapmatching/v5/models/MapMatchingMatching.java) object which extends the DirectionsRoute to begin a nav session. Note that I haven't tried this yet. Make sure your Map Matching request has `steps` set to true.

Comment: Thanks @cammace - do you have a reference link somewhere or some sample code of this? I believe I could be doing this part wrong.

Comment: Hello @FrancisKim, did you manage to make it work with Map Matching API? Thanks